# Accessing the navigation bar from a container view

Tags: swift, swift2, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a view with a navbar and underneath that navbar is a segmented control with its own controller (`BigViewController`). Underneath that are 3 overlapping container views, each with their own controller (`FirstVC, SecondVC, ThirdVC`). In one of the container view controllers, I am trying to access the navbar to put a `rightBarButtonItem` in. I've been trying a few different things but I can't get anything to work. I'm still new to this so I've been trying to work it out but I guess I don't fully understand it.

In `FirstVC` (or any for that matter) I want to put a `rightBarButtonItem` in the navbar. However (I think?) the navbar belongs to `BigViewController`. I think this because I can set a `rightBarButtonItem` in `BigViewController` by using `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sim Incoming", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(simulate))`, but not in `First/Second/ThirdVC`. I've tried adding a prefix `BigViewController.` when in `FirstVC` but that doesn't work. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `parentViewController` property in any of the container view controllers.

Comment: try to use self.parent (Swift 3) in viewDidLayoutSubviews, using in viewDidLoad the same will be nil

Comment: You can also do it from `viewWillAppear`